# Why am I getting corrupt excel files when generating them in my java seam application with apache poi api

Tags: java, seam, apache-poi

I'm trying to create an excel spreadsheat in my seam java application. This is my setup:

**web.xml:**

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Document Store Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.seam.document.DocumentStoreServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Document Store Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/seam/docstore/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**export.xhtml:**

```
<s:resource xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib"
            data="#{showSoldArticlesBean.excelData()}"
            contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel"
            fileName="#{showSoldArticlesBean.excelFileName()}"/>
```

**someother.xhtml:**

```
<s:download src="/export/export.xhtml">
                    <h:outputText value="Download excel"/>
                </s:download>
```

**ShowSoldArticlesBean**

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.jboss.seam.ScopeType;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;       

@Name("showSoldArticlesBean")
@AutoCreate
@MeasureCalls
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
public class ShowSoldArticlesBean implements Serializable {

    @In
    private ArticleAdminBean articleAdminBean;

    @In(required = false)
    @Out(required = false)
    private String fromDate;

    @In(required = false)
    @Out(required = false)
    private String toDate;

    @Out(required = false)
    List<Article> currentArticleList;

    @Begin
    public void initiatePage() {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(fromDate) && StringUtils.isBlank(toDate)) {
            fromDate = aWeekAgo();
            toDate = dateToString(now());
            this.showSoldArticles();
        }
    }

    @End
    public void showSoldArticles() {
        currentArticleList = articleAdminBean.getArticles(fromDate, toDate);
    }

    public byte[] excelData() {

        OutputStream fos = null;

        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

        HSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        style.setBorderTop((short) 6); // double lines border
        style.setBorderBottom((short) 1); // single line border
        style.setFillBackgroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);

        HSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setFontName(HSSFFont.FONT_ARIAL);
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 20);
        font.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        font.setColor(HSSFColor.BLUE.index);
        style.setFont(font);

        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(1);
        HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(1);
        cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("Doing some excel crazy stuff!"));
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
        sheet.autoSizeColumn((short) 1);

        fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(this.excelFileName()));
            workbook.write(fos);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return workbook.getBytes();
    }

    public String excelFileName() {
        return "Somecrap.xls";
    }

}
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.8-beta4</version>
        </dependency>
```

This code generates an excel file that excel complains about and states that the file is corrupt. If I choose to repair the file I get the file with the correct data.

Could you please help me and explain where I'm wrong.

Comment: Why are you writing the workbook to a file, then calling getBytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that sometimes drinking on the job doesn't help you perform better as a programmer =))

I have no idea what was going on in my head when I chose to return the bytes instead of the file.
Thank you Gagravarr for pointing that out.

**Correct code:**

```
public File excelData() {

        File excel = new File("Somecrap.xls");

        OutputStream fos = null;

        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

        HSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        style.setBorderTop((short) 6); // double lines border
        style.setBorderBottom((short) 1); // single line border
        style.setFillBackgroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);

        HSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setFontName(HSSFFont.FONT_ARIAL);
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 20);
        font.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        font.setColor(HSSFColor.BLUE.index);
        //style.setFont(font);

        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(1);
        HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(1);
        cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("Doing some excel crazy stuff!"));
        //cell.setCellStyle(style);
        sheet.autoSizeColumn((short) 1);

        fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(excel);
            workbook.write(fos);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return test;
    }

    public String excelFileName() {
        return "Somecrap.xls";
    }
```

Comment: I think there is a problem in return of this answer, too. You return `test` however there is no any test object definition in the code block. Should it be `excel` File?

Comment: I cant figure out how this code download excel file? 
I am using same method and codes to get word document, it is created but the download doesn't start. Have I missed something?